# C# communicate with DVB-T usb dongle with windows default driver

Tags: c#, winapi, usb, dvb

I am start working to develop windows application with C# that should communicate with DVB-T usb dongle to capture frames of tv channle or get list of available channel on that region and ...

I want to know where to start. Have windows some standard API to communicate with this device?

Comment: I would imagine that that device would show up in DirectShow...

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822703/Features-of-DVB-T-application-development-using-Cs

Comment: thanks to your useful link. it is good link for starting my app.

Comment: This is better project with full Possibilities : https://github.com/dgis/CodeTV